# Show Pivot Chart with Percentage label and Actual Value data table

Tags: excel, charts, pivot, stacked

I have PIVOT CHART with 100% stacked columns. How can I show labels as percentages and data table below it as actual values at the same time?

P.S this is pivot chart, data beneath is expected to change, so no temporary workaround. Excel 2007.